# Getting "undefined" in "this" inside firestore in vuefire

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, vuefire

I'm using firebase-auth and firebase-firestore in my Vue application, with vuefire to retrieve the user data from firestore.

So, I have in my instance:

```
data() {
  return {
      user: firebase.auth().currentUser
  }
},
firestore: {
  userData: db.collection("users").where("uid", "==", this.user.uid)
}
```

But when the code is executed, "this", which should be the instance of Vue, is undefined.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you trying to define a prop called `firestore` on the vue instance?  I think you want that to be a method.

Comment: No, it's spelled correctly... it's the syntax of [vuefire](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuefire/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stuck into the same problem, have no idea why `this` is undefined. As a workaround you can use [Programmatic binding](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuefire/binding-subscriptions.html#programmatic-binding) in `created` hook like this:

```
  created() {
    this.$bind('userData', db.collection("users").where("uid", "==", this.user.uid))
  },
```

Comment: In the meantime I had to find another workaround, but I tested your solution and meets exactly what I needed at the time!

Answer (score 1):

You have to return your data, like this:

```
data() {
    return {
      user: firebase.auth().currentUser
   }
}
```

Comment: My bad when writing the question... return was already defined

Answer (score 1):

You can't react to the store immediately. There is no guarantee at that time that the firebase instance has been created and you're able to use it.

```
data() {
  user: {},
  userData: {}
},
```

Now you can return the *same properties* from your firestore:

```
firestore () {
  return {
    user: firebase.auth().currentUser,
    userData: db.collection("users").where("uid", "==", firebase.auth().currentUser.id)
  }
}
```

Note that in the above `^` you cannot use `this.user.id` because the `user` may not have been written before you attempt to access it. But you can use `firebase.auth().currentUser.id`

Comment: Could they use a `beforeCreate()` hook to prime the component?

Comment: note that the expression `db.collection...` results in a doc reference, not a doc.  The OP must do an async operation (probably `get()`) to get the doc.

Comment: @LenJoseph There isn't any need with `firebase`. The `firestore` definition runs on `created`.

Comment: @danh You don't need to execute it asynchronously here, because the `vue-firestore` plugin actually handles the waiting and defining of the reactive property for you.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - sounds like I'm about to learn something new.  Can you post a link?

Comment: @danh Yep [have a look at this line](https://github.com/gdg-tangier/vue-firestore/blob/master/src/vue-firestore.js#L36). It defines the reactive property and waits for the source before applying it to the container.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I'm not using vue-firestore lib, I'm using [vuefire](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuefire). Does the same apply?

Comment: @leocabrallce My mistake. I am not sure, haven't used that library.